# Android Studio (3.2.1) Instant Run doesn't work with Jacoco 0.8.2?

Tags: android, gradle, jacoco, android-instant-run, instant-run

I created a simple Empty Activity project (Java) with Android Studio 3.2.1. It compiles fine with Instant Run on.

However, when I add Jacoco 0.8.2 to the class path

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    classpath 'org.jacoco:org.jacoco.core:0.8.2' //<--Added this
}
```

When I compile, it get error

```
:app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug 134 ms
```

Disable Instant Run would be okay. Is this a bug in Jacoco or Android sdk?

**Updated with Error Description**

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:103)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:256)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:249)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:238)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:663)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:597)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at com.android.builder.profile.Recorder$Block.handleException(Recorder.java:55)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:104)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:230)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:124)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:113)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.InstantRunTransform.doTransform(InstantRunTransform.java:320)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.InstantRunTransform.transform(InstantRunTransform.java:186)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:239)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:235)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.getThrowableException(ForkJoinTask.java:593)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.reportException(ForkJoinTask.java:677)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.join(ForkJoinTask.java:720)
    at com.android.ide.common.internal.WaitableExecutor.waitForTasksWithQuickFail(WaitableExecutor.java:146)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.InstantRunTransform.doTransform(InstantRunTransform.java:315)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis.BasicInterpreter.<init>(BasicInterpreter.java:66)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.incremental.ConstructorBuilder$1.<init>(ConstructorBuilder.java:127)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.incremental.ConstructorBuilder.build(ConstructorBuilder.java:127)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.incremental.IncrementalSupportVisitor.visitMethod(IncrementalSupportVisitor.java:223)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visitMethod(ClassVisitor.java:327)
    at org.objectweb.asm.commons.SerialVersionUIDAdder.visitMethod(SerialVersionUIDAdder.java:236)
    at org.objectweb.asm.tree.MethodNode.accept(MethodNode.java:686)
    at org.objectweb.asm.tree.ClassNode.accept(ClassNode.java:436)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.incremental.IncrementalVisitor.instrumentClass(IncrementalVisitor.java:365)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.InstantRunTransform.transformToClasses2Format(InstantRunTransform.java:414)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.InstantRunTransform.lambda$doTransform$4(InstantRunTransform.java:276)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.InstantRunTransform.lambda$null$5(InstantRunTransform.java:305)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
```

Comment: An issue raised to Jacoco https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/779

Comment: this is the name of a Gradle task and not an error description; adding it to the class-path does not suffice to make it work.

Comment: Issue file to google as per https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/118709917

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting my answer at https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/779#issuecomment-434281431 :

> As you can see - exception originates from
>   `com.android.build.gradle.internal`:
>
> ```
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
>   at org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis.BasicInterpreter.<init>(BasicInterpreter.java:66)
>   at com.android.build.gradle.internal.incremental.ConstructorBuilder$1.<init>(ConstructorBuilder.java:127)
>   at com.android.build.gradle.internal.incremental.ConstructorBuilder.build(ConstructorBuilder.java:127)
>   at com.android.build.gradle.internal.incremental.IncrementalSupportVisitor.visitMethod(IncrementalSupportVisitor.java:223)
>   at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visitMethod(ClassVisitor.java:327)
>   at org.objectweb.asm.commons.SerialVersionUIDAdder.visitMethod(SerialVersionUIDAdder.java:236)
>   at org.objectweb.asm.tree.MethodNode.accept(MethodNode.java:686)
>   at org.objectweb.asm.tree.ClassNode.accept(ClassNode.java:436)
>   at com.android.build.gradle.internal.incremental.IncrementalVisitor.instrumentClass(IncrementalVisitor.java:365)
>   at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.InstantRunTransform.transformToClasses2Format(InstantRunTransform.java:414)
>   at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.InstantRunTransform.lambda$doTransform$4(InstantRunTransform.java:276)
>   at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.InstantRunTransform.lambda$null$5(InstantRunTransform.java:305)
> ```
>
> Code of
>   `com.android.build.gradle.internal.incremental.ConstructorBuilder.build`
>   that causes exception  at
>   [`ConstructorBuilder.java:127`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/studio-master-dev/build-system/instant-run-instrumentation/src/main/java/com/android/build/gradle/internal/incremental/ConstructorBuilder.java#127):
>
> ```
> BasicInterpreter interpreter = new BasicInterpreter() {
> ```
>
> which is incorrect according to Javadoc of constructor
>   `org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis.BasicInterpreter` that throws
>   exception at
>   [`BasicInterpreter.java:66`](https://gitlab.ow2.org/asm/asm/blob/ASM_6_2_1/asm-analysis/src/main/java/org/objectweb/asm/tree/analysis/BasicInterpreter.java#L66):
>
> ```
>   /**
>    * Constructs a new {@link BasicInterpreter} for the latest ASM API version. <i>Subclasses must
>    * not use this constructor</i>. Instead, they must use the {@link #BasicInterpreter(int)}
>    * version.
>    */
>   public BasicInterpreter() {
>     super(ASM6);
>     if (getClass() != BasicInterpreter.class) {
>       throw new IllegalStateException();
>     }
>   }
> ```
>
> Clearly this should be reported to developers of Android SDK -
>   https://developer.android.com/studio/report-bugs.html
>
> One might wonder why exception doesn't happen without last line in
>
> ```
> dependencies {
>     classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
>     classpath 'org.jacoco:org.jacoco.core:0.8.2'
> ```
>
> And the reason is similar to
>   https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/639#issuecomment-355424756 -
>   multiple ASM versions in classpath:
>
> - JaCoCo 0.8.2 requires ASM 6.2.1 and `org.jacoco:org.jacoco.core:0.8.2` correctly declares dependencies on
>     ASM
> - [exception was added in ASM 6.1](https://gitlab.ow2.org/asm/asm/commit/70960d92caff136011995b3acd2e04994aa4ad50#88fd855ebd592f23b1e0242fe38b1275a1f7a9f6_54_65)
> - `com.android.build.gradle.internal.incremental.ConstructorBuilder` most likely was developed / uses older version of ASM
>
> To avoid such classpath issues, developers of Android SDK can
>   reconsider the way they execute JaCoCo and for example use dedicated
>   ClassLoader.
>
> As a possible workaround you can try to use JaCoCo 0.8.1 that depends
>   on ASM 6.0

Comment: Thanks. Issue file to google as per https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/118709917

Comment: @Elye If the answer is helpful / correct, please consider upvoting / marking it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

As a possible workaround you can try to use JaCoCo `0.8.1` that depends on ASM 6.0.